# How to use conditional operator in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

What I am trying to retrieve is the contact number. I have a relation called BusinessDetails and the fields are `Name`,`Description`, `PhoneNum`, `MobileNum`. Case of contact number are as follows:

1. I can have both MobileNum and PhoneNum.
2. I can have any one of them
3. I can't have both of them

I am trying this piece of sql select statement and it is quite good when there are both number. but in the `2` and `3` case there is unnecessary comma associated with it. My sql is

```
   SELECT Business.PhoneNum+','+Business.MobileNum AS ContactNumber 
     FROM dbo.BusinessDetails AS Business
```

Can some body help me out for removing comma in 2nd and 3rd case?

Comment: My sql only and should be applicable for sql ans sql server r2 as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case` (general solution which works for almost all DBMS's):

```
select case
         when PhoneNum is null then -- MobileNum only
           MobileNum
         when MobileNum is null then -- PhoneNum only
           PhoneNum
         when (PhoneNum is not null) and (MobileNum is not null) then -- Both
           MobileNum || ',' || PhoneNum
         else -- Neither MobileNum no PhoneNum  
           'No Phone'
       end as ContactNumber      
  from dbo.BusinessDetails as Business
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`CONCAT_WS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws), like this:

```
select CONCAT_WS(',', Business.PhoneNum, Business.MobileNum) 
from dbo.BusinessDetails as Business
```

Comment: Which product, version? SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @Arunesh tags in the post mentioned `mysql`